Same Tool Strip Drop Down Items for Different Right Click Window Items WindowsForm C#
I have 2 Right click window items with some same name/function items in the drop down. How do I make this possible? Win form seems not to let me have the same exact items in different right click window items.
Code:
.
.
RightClickWindow.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { InsertAbove, InsertBelow });
.
.
InsertAbove.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { AddName, AddSSN, AddHeight, AddWeight });
.
.
InsertBelow.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { AddName, AddSSN, AddJob, AddHobby });
.
.

Result: AddName and AddSSN only show in InsertBelow and is not shown in InsertAbove. They only shows in InsertAbove if I remove them in InsertBelow.
I tried copied and pasted then change the names of the items (AddNameAbove, AddNameBelow, AddSSNAbove, AddSSNBelow,...) but it looks like a mess in my designer.cs since I have many same items that need to be on different right click window items.

What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?

This might be trickier than it sounds. The easy part is making the singleton collection of ToolStripItem:
ToolStripItem[] CommonItems
{
    get
    {
        if (_commonItemsSingleton is null)
        {
            var clickableItem = new ToolStripMenuItem
            {
                Text = "Simple click"
            };
            clickableItem.Click += SimpleClick_Clicked;

            var comboBoxItem = new ToolStripComboBox
            {
                DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList,
            };

            comboBoxItem.Items.AddRange(new[]
            {
                "Select",
                "Item A",
                "Item B",
                "Item C",
            });

            comboBoxItem.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBoxItem.SelectedIndexChanged += async (sender, e) =>{ await Task.Delay(10); ContextMenuStrip?.Close(); };
            comboBoxItem.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged; 
            _commonItemsSingleton = new ToolStripItem[]
            {
                clickableItem,
                new ToolStripSeparator(),
                comboBoxItem,
            };
        }
        return _commonItemsSingleton;
    }
}
ToolStripItem[]? _commonItemsSingleton = default;


But as you've observed:

Win form seems not to let me have the same exact items in different right click window items.

Since each of these items can only have one Parent at a time, you can't just AddRange to both InsertAbove and InsertBelow. You have to game the system a little bit by loading them on-demand when  InsertAbove or InsertBelow dynamically raise the DropDownOpening event.
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ContextMenuStrip = RightClickWindow;

    var InsertAbove = new ToolStripMenuItem { Text = "InsertAbove", AutoSize = true };
    var InsertBelow = new ToolStripMenuItem { Text = "InsertBelow", AutoSize = true };
    foreach (var tsmi in new[] { InsertAbove, InsertBelow })
    {
        tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem());    // Placeholder ensures ► visible
        tsmi.DropDownOpening += (sender, e) =>
        {
            tsmi.DropDownItems.Clear();
            tsmi.DropDownItems.AddRange(CommonItems);
        };
        tsmi.DropDownClosed += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            // This delay ensures that the handler will still have
            // access to the OwnerItem. We'll probably want to know
            // whether the call was made by InsertAbove or InsertBelow
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
            tsmi.DropDownItems.Clear();
            tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem()); // Placeholder
        };
        RightClickWindow.Items.Add(tsmi);
    }
}



Determine the caller
Since the two drop down menus now do (literally) identical things, it may be important to inspect the OwnerItem to determine whether it was called by [InsertAbove] or [InsertBelow]. For example:
private void SimpleClick_Clicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ToolStripItem tsi)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            text: tsi.Text, caption: $"Called by {tsi.OwnerItem?.Text}");
    }
}



Clone
